# My app installs outside Google play not showing updates

Tags: android

I have published my app on google play  but I have about 1000 app installs from other direct links before it.i have published signed app with same certificate but with a newer version.when I searched my app on play store on my own device which has a previous version of this app it only shows installed not update.have I done anything wrong?

Comment: did you increase the `android:versionCode`?

Comment: Not of course . By default it is 1 if I'm not wrong.

Comment: So I have to change it?

Comment: Play Store checks the number to offer an update. It will only ever update for a higher number.

Comment: Thanks I'm working on it

Comment: Yah it works for me. Thanks again